# Counting vowels in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Trying to get better in Lisp, I came across the following problem:

```
(defun countVowels (string)
  (setf vowels (list 'a 0 'e 0 'i 0 'o 0 'u 0))
  (loop for ch across string
        when (member ch vowels)
        do (incf (getf vowels ch)))
  (format t "~{~a~^, ~}" vowels))
```

In my opinion, this counts every vowel by incrementing the plist. However, when I invoke the function with e.g.

```
(countVowels "test")
```

the output is

```
A, 0, E, 0, I, 0, O, 0, U, 0
```

Comment: Also: the variable `vowels` is undefined. You need to define local variables. Use `let` or `let*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is incorrect. You're searching for characters in a list of symbols. To get it minimally working, you'll need to initialize `vowels` as

```
  (setf vowels (list #\a 0 #\e 0 #\i 0 #\o 0 #\u 0))
```

However, it still has some issues. `setf` is used to assign to existing variables, not create new ones. While it will fall back to creating variables, SBCL issues a warning for this. We should be using `let` instead, or simply a `with` block inside the `loop` macro.

Additionally, the naming convention is just flat lying to you. Common Lisp is case-insensitive, so there's no difference between `countVowels` and `COUNTVOWELS`, or even `CoUnTvOwElS`. We usually tend to stick to one case in Common Lisp, just to keep things consistent.

Finally, there's no compelling reason to print inside the function. That just takes power away from the caller. Return the plist instead and let the caller decide what to do with it. If you don't want to rely heavily on the `loop` macro, you can write

```
(defun count-vowels (string)
  (let ((vowels (list #\a 0 #\e 0 #\i 0 #\o 0 #\u 0)))
    (loop for ch across string
          when (getf vowels ch)
          do (incf (getf vowels ch)))
    vowels))

(format t "~{~a~^, ~}" (count-vowels "test"))
```

or you can go all-in on `loop` and write

```
(defun count-vowels (string)
  (loop with vowels = (list #\a 0 #\e 0 #\i 0 #\o 0 #\u 0)
        for ch across string
        when (getf vowels ch)
        do (incf (getf vowels ch))
        finally (return vowels)))

(format t "~{~a~^, ~}" (count-vowels "test"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, much appreciated. See, I do like the concepts of LISP but sometimes it's really hard as it is so much different to other languages.

Comment: Some detailed lisp tutorial with excercises would be perfect. Sure, I did read some books on the topic (Land of Lisp, Practical Common Lisp, the like) but this would still be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a hash table instead of a plist (or alist or other list construct), to get better performance - `O(1)` operations instead of `O(N)`. Example, using a couple of convenience functions from [Alexandria](https://alexandria.common-lisp.dev/):

```lisp
(ql:quickload :alexandria)
(defun count-vowels (string)
  (loop with vowels = (alexandria:plist-hash-table '(#\a 0 #\e 0 #\i 0 #\o 0 #\u 0) :test 'eql)
        for ch across string
        when (gethash (char-downcase ch) vowels)
          do (incf (gethash (char-downcase ch) vowels))
        finally (return vowels)))
```

And in action:

```lisp
CL-USER> (alexandria:hash-table-plist (count-vowels "test"))
(#\i 0 #\e 1 #\o 0 #\a 0 #\u 0)
```

Just because Lisp languages make it easy to use lists doesn't mean they're always the most appropriate data structure. Also note how this version downcases the characters so both, say, E and e count as the same character for counting purposes.

Comment: The plist or alist version is about 2 to 3 times faster, though (quick tests on my machine). "Just because some data structure has an asymptotically better average case performance doesn't mean it's always the most appropriate one". Alist /are/ better than hash-tables when you have a small number of keys.

Comment: Thank you as well. However, I'd like to learn LISP from the bottom and while external libraries sure can make life easier, I just want to grasp the essentials.

Comment: @jan Hash tables aren't an external library (but unlike other container types CL doesn't have an easy way to specify the initial contents when creating them; de-facto standard libraries like Alexandria help fill in the gaps and are indispensable)

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another implementation to show that you can entirely avoid lists too if you want:

```
(defun count-letters (string &optional (letters "aeiouy"))
  (loop
    :with counters = (make-array (length letters) :initial-element 0)
    :for c :across string
    :for p = (position c letters :test #'char-equal)
    :when p
    :do (incf (aref counters p))
    :finally (return counters)))
```

The resulting counter vector is sorted according to the input set of letters, so you can build an association list if you want as follows:

```
(defun count-vowels (string &aux (vowels "aeiouy"))
  (map 'list #'cons vowels (count-letters string vowels)))
```

(nb. `&aux` is just a way to introduce variables without a `let`)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll look into it. The `:` are part of the code?

Comment: Yes, symbols starting with a colon are members of the "KEYWORD" package, I sometimes use these in LOOP so that the code highlighter colors them differently, but LOOP doesn't care, the macro just checks e.g. that there is a symbol whose name is "FOR" (symbols are made up of a name, a string, and a home package (an object of type package))

Comment: Which IDE are you using (if any)?

Comment: Emacs with Slime/Swank, which acts like a language server (except that that the server is executed in the same runtime as the rest of the code); https://slime.common-lisp.dev/